# HTACCESS friendly urls with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url

I have a problem.

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domena.pl(.*) [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domena.pl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)$ index.php?$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z-]+)$ index.php?$1=$2
```

I need to redirect urls like:
domena.pl/index.php?aktualnosci to domena.pl/aktualnosci

I will trying with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} aktualnosci
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /aktualnosci? [L,R=301]
```

But this is redirect loop..
Also I have couple urls which are spaces and I wanna change this spaces to line and Polish characters like ąćźż to aczz.

Any one can help?

Comment: Non standard characters need to be urlencoded, not sure wether this gonna work like you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domena.pl(.*) [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domena.pl/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?([^\s=]+?)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z-]+)$ index.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ok. Thank You.. but what with urls like:

    http://www.domena.pl/index.php?galeria=test

they are redirect to after changes:

    http://www.domena.pl/galeria=test

And how I can change empty spaces to - and Polish characters to universal?
Ex.

    http://www.domena.pl/index.php?galeria=ładne zdjęcia

I wanna url like this:

    http://www.domena.pl/galeria/ladne-zdjecia

Comment: ok check updated rule. It will ignore `?galeria=test` URI. Also please don't add a new question from comments. If this works for original requirement then accept this answer and ask a new question.